# difference in 2 template dependent typename kinds

Tags: c++, templates

From Scott Meyers's book, names in a template that are dependent on a template parameter are called **dependent names**. 
(When a dependent name is nested inside a class, I call it a nested dependent name)

So its necessary to use "typename" keyword before the dependent name, right?

```
template<typename C>
void print2nd(const C& container) {
typename C::const_iterator iter(container.begin()); 
...
}
```

But why in this code, taken from Josuttis book, std::vector that is another template's instantiation which is obviously dependent on T, they do not use "typename" here:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
    (?typename?) std::vector<T> elems;
...
};
```

It all looks confusing especially with another example from Meyers:

```
template<typename IterT> 
void workWithIterator(IterT iter) {
    typename std::iterator_traits<IterT>::value_type temp(*iter);
... }
```

They look all the same to me. How do you differentiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have

```
typename C::const_iterator iter(container.begin());
```

The `const_iterator` part is a type that depends on what `C` is.  So you need `typename` there to tell the compiler that `C::const_iterator` is a type.

In

```
std::vector<T> elems;
```

You are declaring a `std::vector` whose elements are of type `T`.  You do not need `typename` there at all.  Even though `vector` *depends* on the type `T` it is not a name dependent on what `T` is.

You can read more about when and where `typename` and `template` are required at [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: I'm struggling to get the difference :) So, when compiler sees "C::const_iterator" its unknown before instantiation/ substitution of C for any concrete type, what the "const_iterator" is, right? But the "std::vector<T>" also depends on the exact concrete T, or its not? Just because IT IS the instantiation?

Comment: Another example from Meyers refers to something similar to vector<T> but with "typename" keyword still:
template<typename IterT> 
void workWithIterator(IterT iter) {
   typename std::iterator_traits<IterT>::value_type temp(*iter);
... }
why here ? what is the difference of iterator_traits<T> with vector<T> ?

Comment: @barney When the compiler sees `some_name::some_other_name` it does not expect to see a type when `some_name` is a template type.  So you use `typename` to tell it is a name and not a non-name like it assumes.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example (`typename C::const_iterator`), `const_iterator` cannot be known to the compiler firsthand: it could be a static member, for instance. This is why you need to prefix the declaration with `typename`, to indicate it is a type.

In the second example, the compiler knows `std::vector<T>` is a type, even without knowing what is `T`. Which is why `typename` is not needed in this case.

Comment: How exactly do you know, that C::const_iterator cannot be known? Is it because its nested to unknown type C ? Then, here's another example from Meyers:
template<typename IterT> 
void workWithIterator(IterT iter) {
    typename std::iterator_traits<IterT>::value_type temp(*iter);
... 
}

Comment: @barney Yes, it is because it is nested in `C`, so the compiler has a hard time deciding at this point what is `const_iterator`. As mentioned, you could have a `static int const_iterator` nested in `C`, which is a static member named `const_iterator` of type `int`, not a type. But prefixing with `typename` in this case means "`const_iterator` is a type name". However, `std::vector<>` is a type (which takes a template parameter), and the compiler knows that, so the compiler figures that without knowing the exact type of `C`.

Comment: @barney For the other example you mention (`std::iterator_traits<IterT>::value_type`): `iterator_traits` is known as a type, but the compiler does not know what is within the specific `iterator_traits<IterT>` implementation (because the class could be specialized for the type behind `IterT`), so you need to use `typename` to indicate you refer to a type, just like the `C::const_iterator` example.